# Restarting an Activity ends in IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android

I am trying to snooze an alarm, pressing the snooze button restarts the same activity after a predefined time. However, When I press the snooze button, App crashes , and in logcat I am provided with error : `java.lang.IllegalStateException` . Here is the code I use to snooze, Help me find where I am doing wrong and the best alternative to fix it.  Thanks,

```
  public void snoozeup(View view)
{
    SharedPreferences sa = getSharedPreferences("SnoozeList", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int snox = sa.getInt("SnoozeX",0);

    if(snox==2) {

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable x = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(Time_Date.this, Time_Date.class));
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(x, 120000);

    }

    else if(snox==3) {

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable x = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(Time_Date.this, Time_Date.class));
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(x, 180000);

    }
    else if(snox==5) {

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable x = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(Time_Date.this, Time_Date.class));
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(x, 300000);

    }
    else if(snox==10) {

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable x = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(Time_Date.this, Time_Date.class));
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(x, 600000);

    }
    else
    {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable x = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(Time_Date.this, Time_Date.class));
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(x, 180000);

    }

    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    voicePlayer.stop();
    voicePlayer.release();
    songPlayer.stop();
    songPlayer.release();



    finish();
}
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
            at zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia.Time_Date$4.run(Time_Date.java:199)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
09-15 11:49:25.805    1793-1793/zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1793 SIG: 9
```

Also, I am using an `isPlaying()` method in this Activity, And here is how it is:

```
 try {
        final Handler hlr = new Handler();

        final Runnable looper = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (mp != null) {

                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.stop();
                    }

                }


                mp.start();

            }
        };


        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                hlr.postDelayed(looper, 5000);
            }
        });

    }
    catch(IllegalStateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace please.

Comment: I've posted the full stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the `isPlaying()` condition for these lines too

```
mp.stop();
mp.release();
voicePlayer.stop();
voicePlayer.release();
songPlayer.stop();
songPlayer.release();
```

like this

```
if(mp.isPlaying()) {
   mp.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> suppose if your `mp` in already in `stop` state and you are trying to
>   `stop` again so you will get `java.lang.IllegalStateException`.

also check if your resources are not `null` like `mp,voicePlayer,songPlayer`

> you should check `isPlaying()` before `stop()`

do check like:

```
      try {
             if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
                Log.d("TAG------->", "mp is running");
                mp.stop();
                Log.d("TAG------->", "mp is stopped");
                mp.release();
                Log.d("TAG------->", "mp is released");

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Should I check it for all the MediaPlayer instances or just `mp` ?

Comment: all instances for whom you are trying to change their state.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `stop()` method without check Is it playing or not. If it is not playing and you call `stop()` method than illegalStateException occur so 
do check whether mediaPlayer instanse `isPlaying()` or not.

```
if(mp.isPlaying()){
    mp.stop();
}
```